# Confusion about a simple general topology problem

Tags: general-topology

If $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, do we have that $U\times \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Here $\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{m}$ both equip with the standard topology.

Comment: Have you tried checking whether $U \times \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ satisfies the definition of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Depends on the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Note $U \times \Bbb R^{n - m} = \pi^{-1}(U)$ where $\pi$ is the projection map
$$
\pi : \Bbb R^n \ni (x_1, \ldots, x_m, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \ldots, x_m) \in \Bbb R^m
$$ and as projection maps are continuous the inverse image of an open set is an open set.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we do.  Because $U×\Bbb R^{n-m}$ is the product of open sets.  Those sets are by definition open in $\Bbb R^n$.

You may wish to look up [product topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) ,  or "box topology", which agrees with the product topology on finite products, or "standard topology on $\Bbb R^n$".

You could use the projection, $\pi$, onto the first $m$ coordinates. The standard topology is defined to be the coarsest topology which makes this map continuous. But $U$ is open.   Thus, by definition,  $U×\Bbb R^{n-m}=\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open.